# Websphere application server for developers linux command line install

Tags: installation, websphere

I tried to install websphere application server for developer v8.5. I've already installed the installation manager. Then I download the image from [here](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=swerpws-wasdevdl85&S_PKG=500023135&S_CMP=web_dw_rt_swd&lang=en_US&cp=UTF-8&dlmethod=http#): all the three parts of WebSphere Application Server for Developers, Installation Manager Repository. Cause my linux has no GUI, so I unzipped the file and tried to use installation manager to install it.

I used :
     `./imcl listAvailablePackages -repositories /home/user/tmp/wasdev_installer/repository.config` to verify that the package exist.

Then I ran :    `./imcl install com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85_8.5.5000.20130514_1044 -repositories /home/user/tmp/wasdev_installer/repository.config -installationDirectory /home/user/Websphere_v85 -accessRights nonAdmin -acceptLicense`

But I always got errors like :

> ERROR:         The silent installation process does not support
>   installing packages that are contained on multiple media discs.
>
> ```
> CRIMC1017E ERROR:     Failed to locate zip com.ibm.websphere.batch_136_all.all 8.5.5000.201305110146.
>
> Cannot find the table of contents file for an artifact in the repository. Table of contents files are located under the atoc directory in the repository.
>
> If the repository files were transferred from a different location, verify that the files were not altered during the transfer operation. Copy the repository files to a different location and install from that location.
> ```

I re-unzipped the file, but didn't help. Was I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by unzipping all files to one directory. The file part1 contains disk1, so the other files should be put under the directory of part1, which means in the same level of disk1 directory.

Answer (score 0):

Deepending on what programming models you're using, you could always try the WebSphe Liberty Profile artefact install: https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/. It doesn't support every programming model that the full profile does, but it's a super-easy install, and easy to get going with as a development environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to bother with downloading and decompressing archives containing the Installation Manager repositories, then there is a much easier and simpler process for getting WebSphere Application Server for Developers installed.

Once you have IBM Installation Manager installed, you only need to provide the repository location to where the IBM hosted WebSphere Application Server for Developers repository is located.  For instance, to install WAS for Developers version 8.0 or version 8.5, you simply add one of the repository locations to the repository preferences.

- V8.0: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V8WASDeveloperILAN
- V8.5: http://www.ibm.com/software/repositorymanager/V85WASDeveloperILAN

Instructions for [installing WAS for Developers using IBM hosted repositories](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/WAS_traditional_for_Developers) in available on WASDev.net.

You could even use the IBM hosted repositories in your [command line installation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_installation_dist_cl.html) or [response file installation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_installation_dist_silent.html), as long as you create a secure storage file with you MY IBM ID credentials for authenticating with the IBM servers, as described in the WebSphere Knowledge Center.

Alternatively, you can use the IBM Package Utility (a companion to Installation Manager), to reconstruct the IBM hosted repository on your local machine. The advantage to using PU is that you will be able to create a local repository that also includes the fixpack level of your own choosing rather than having to go get a fixpack from IBM Fix Central and then updating the installation afterwards.

Information on [creating local repositories with Packaging Utility](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.installation.base.doc/ae/tins_creating_cust_reps.html) is available in the WebSphere Knowledge Center.